# What does this shell script fragment do?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to read shell script which I haven't worked with before... What does this code do?

```
# Setup some command defaults (can be overriden by the config)
MYSQL=${MYSQL:-`which mysql`}
MYSQLDUMP=${MYSQLDUMP:-`which mysqldump`}
PHP=${PHP:-`which php`}
```

I have a feeling it determines the location of php, mysql and mysqldump if the variable is not already defined.  Is that correct?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If variable is undefined or is the empty string, it replaces it with the result of the `which` command so that it serves as a default value.

Side note, you could make it more robust by using `type -P mysql` or `hash mysql` instead of `which mysql` since implementations of `which` may differ.

see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html and [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: The first sentence should begin "If the variable is undefined or is the empty string" since the operator is ':-' rather than '-'.